# if $ \ p_0 \ $ is a fixed prime , then there exists some $ \ a_0 \in \phi(4p_0) \ $

Tags: number-theory

Consider the theorem:

**Theorem:**

Let $ \ p_0 \ $ be a fixed prime. Then, for an odd prime $ \ p \ ( \neq p_0 ) \ $  the equation  $ \ x^2=p_0 \ (mod \ p) \ $ has a solution if and only if $ \ p=\pm l^2 \ \ (mod \ 4p_0) \ $ when $ \ l \in \{0,........., 4p-1 \} \ $  is odd.

**Now use the above theorem to show** that if $ \ p_0 \ $ is a fixed prime , then there exists some $ \ a_0 \in \phi(4p_0) \ $ and some $ \ b_0 \in \phi(4p_0) \ $ such that for any prime $ \ p \ $ such that $ \ p =a_0 \ (mod \ 4p_0) \ $ , we have  $ \ \left( \frac{p_0}{p} \right) =1 \ $ and for any prime $ \ q \ $  such that $ \ q = b_0 \ (mod \ 4p_0) $ , we have $ \ \left( \frac{p_0}{q} \right) =-1 \ $

**Answer:**

I am getting no way to hit the question .

Can someone help me

Comment: You had better tell us what $\phi$ means.

Comment: Here $ \phi \ $ is Euler phi-function

Comment: Then $\phi(4p_0)$ is a number, not a set, so what does it mean for $a_0$ to be an element?

Comment: oh yeas . I did not look . So the question is somewhere faulty